# TypeError: glob is not a function after updating typechain-hardhat to @typechain/hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, error, typescript, typechain

After updating project from typechain-hardhat to @typechain/hardhat package.

Compilation of project throws **TypeError: glob is not a function** error. And I can not run scripts, tests, compile etc.

```
An unexpected error occurred:

TypeError: glob is not a function
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\user\SmartContracts\trade-smart-contracts\node_modules\@typechain\hardhat\src\index.ts:70:22)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\user\SmartContracts\trade-smart-contracts\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\user\SmartContracts\trade-smart-contracts\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
    at OverriddenTaskDefinition._action (C:\Users\user\SmartContracts\trade-smart-contracts\node_modules\@typechain\hardhat\src\index.ts:29:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\user\SmartContracts\trade-smart-contracts\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\user\SmartContracts\trade-smart-contracts\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\user\SmartContracts\trade-smart-contracts\node_modules\hardhat\src\builtin-tasks\compile.ts:1331:63)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\user\SmartContracts\trade-smart-contracts\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\user\SmartContracts\trade-smart-contracts\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\user\SmartContracts\trade-smart-contracts\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue:
the problem was that the previous `typechain-hardhat` package generated the `typechain` folder, but now `@typechain/hardhat` generates `typechain-types` folder

Comment: How did you resolve this